# How to map the Jersey Client's response to a Generic List of Bean/Value Object using Jackson Feature

Tags: generics, jackson, apache-httpclient-4.x, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am trying to make my Rest client generic, so that I could use the same client class to instantiate to retrive a list of VO like books,authors,publishers or any think similar VO . Below is the Generic class I am working on, but I am only getting a List of LinkedHashMap retrieved and not that of valueobject(Book).
I had used [hascode's rest client feature example](http://www.hascode.com/2013/12/jax-rs-2-0-rest-client-features-by-example/) for generating the rest service

```
public class GenericRestClient<T> {

private final Client client;

public GenericRestClient() {
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    client.register(JacksonFeature.class);
}


private List invokeGetService(String serviceUrl){

    List results = null;
    try {

        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(serviceUrl);

        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =
            webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

         //response;
        //If I use  the class generic type variable, I am getting a List of LinkedHashMap and not List of the value object
        GenericType<List<T>> responseType = new GenericType<List<T>>() {};

        //Using below I am getting the list of books properly
       //GenericType<List<Book>> responseType = new GenericType<List<Book>>() { };
        results =   invocationBuilder.get(responseType);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericRestClient<Book> restClient = new GenericRestClient<Book>();

    System.out.println(restClient.invokeGetService("http://localhost:8080/library/books").get(0).toString());

}
```

}

My POM dependencies are

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

Let me know if I could achieve it or is it not possible using Generics

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by making the constructor accept generictype and passed that generictype to invocationbuilders get method

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how I do it. Will be helpful for the future reader.

```
    import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.lang.reflect.Type;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
    }.getType();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
    formData.add("key1", "value1");
    formData.add("key1", "value2");
    WebTarget webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("https://some.server.url/");
    String response = webTarget.path("subpath/subpath2").request().post(Entity.form(formData), String.class);
    Map<String, String> gsonResponse = gson.fromJson(response, type);
```